# RailsAdmin - Limit associated records using Associations-scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-admin

According to the following seemingly-perfect project wiki article, I should be able to limit number of associated records to be displayed with ease.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Associations-scoping

However, I can't seem to make it work. I have the following code:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients, through :assignments

  rails_admin do
    configure :patients do
      associated_collection_cache_all false
      associated_collection_scope do
        Proc.new { |scope|
          scope = scope.limit(1)
        }
      end
    end
end
```

But this doesn't do anything. Also, it's supposed to limit the number of records at 30 by default, but it's pulling everything. I double checked the rails_admin.rb configuration file, and there is nothing that overrides the value.

Another problem I am seeing is that sometimes I notice runaway Ruby processes when using the Admin functionalities. I googled to see if anyone else had the similar problem, but I couldn't find any posts.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like that with `associated_collection_cache_all` set to `true`, the `limit` is not at all taken into account. But if you're loading only a couple dozen records of your associated scope, there's no reason not to preload all them. Remove the `associated_collection_cache_all false` line, and it should work perfectly with your limit.

Comment: I have tried that before, but for some odd reason, it didn't do anything. Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: That's weird. When I removed that line it worked perfectly for me. What version of `rails_admin` & `rails` are you using?